# Has the Google Cloud Dataproc preview image's Spark version changed?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc

I recently started a Spark cluster on Google Cloud Dataproc using the 'preview' image. According to the documentation, the preview image's Spark version is '2.1.0', however running `spark-shell --version` reveals that the cluster is in fact running Spark 2.2.0. This is a problem for us, because our version of `spark-avro` is not compatible with Spark 2.2.0. Is anyone else experiencing this issue? I haven't been able to find any trace of an official announcement from Google regarding the version bump.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry about that, it appears the minor release notes for the recent `preview` image update got lost in the ether; the documentation should hopefully be updated by tomorrow. Indeed you're right that the current Dataproc `preview` version is now Spark 2.2.0. If you need to pin to a known working older preview image, you can try:

```
gcloud dataproc clusters create --image https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/cloud-dataproc/global/images/dataproc-1-2-20170227-145329
```

That should contain Spark 2.1.0. That said, keep in mind that in general it's always possible that incompatible changes may be made in new preview images, and pinning to that older preview image isn't guaranteed to continue working long term.

In your case, do you happen to know whether you're hitting this [issue filed on spark-avro](https://github.com/databricks/spark-avro/issues/240) or is it something specific to your version? Ideally we should get you updated to Spark 2.2, since an official (non-preview) image version is going to be imminent with Spark 2.2.

Comment: Many thanks for the response, Dennis. We are hitting the linked issue on spark-avro. My intention is to upgrade to 2.2.0 as soon as that issue is fixed. We'll use the workaround you suggested in the meantime. Really looking forward to the official image release!

Comment: Thanks for confirming the issue! We'll be sure to keep a close eye on the spark-avro fix, which appears to be nicely in progress already: https://github.com/databricks/spark-avro/pull/242